# Puppet for patching software

Tags: puppet, patch, puppet-enterprise

I am totally new to Puppet. I am using Puppet Enterprise 3.7 and have a lab set up with a puppet master and puppet agents running on Linux CentOS. The primary aim is to use Puppet automation as an auditing and patching tool.
I would like to audit all my agent servers for what packages that are installed in it and then push them to patch if required.  I have done a fair bit of reading but the information i get is very vague.

I would appreciate any help on how and where to start with the process. I know it is a vague question, but any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: This question is way too broad. Please add at least some references to what you read, and why you don't think it is helpful to you.

Answer (score 1):

For auditing, there is a native Puppet metaparameter of [audit](https://docs.puppetlabs.com/references/latest/metaparameter.html#audit):

```
file { '/etc/hosts':
  audit => [ owner, group, mode ],
}
```

Puppet will then generate auditing log messages, which are available in your standard Puppet reports:

```
audit change: previously recorded value owner root has been changed to owner james
```

([Taken from the PuppetLabs blog post about auditing](http://puppetlabs.com/blog/problem-patch-management-all-humans))

For patch-management, it's a bit different. [You shouldn't really think of Puppet as a patch-management tool](http://puppetlabs.com/blog/problem-patch-management-all-humans). It can do it, because Puppet can do anything that any script or manual work can perform/

One approach that you can use Puppet patch-management for is:

- Manage your own mirrors of external package repositories with Puppet
- Control when you update those mirrors when a patch comes out Have
- Puppet update packages on a rough schedule with an Exec resource,
  cron-job etc.

There's a pretty good ServerFault post explaining this approach [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/387986/how-do-you-approach-centralised-patch-management-for-linux).